# Show Div on Button Click

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I  am trying to show a loading div on button click, but it is not working at the moment.

Javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function (e) {      
            $('#BtnSend').click(function () {
                $('#<%= loading.ClientID %>').toggle("slow");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Div:

```
<div id="loading" class="Loading" runat="server" visible="false">
  <div class="loadingImg">
    <img src="../Images/loading.gif" alt="loading" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

button:

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnSend" runat="server" Text="SEND" 
            onclick="BtnSend_Click" CssClass="pressbutton2" Height="36px" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Also how can I call the same javascript code in the jsfiddle above within code (c#)?

Comment: Include jQuery library in  fiddle See http://jsfiddle.net/fUBPB/3/

Comment: Have you added required jQuery library.

Comment: added in my solution but still not working in asp.net

Comment: hey click on run to update..den it should work as i ahve suggested below

Comment: Also Remove onClick="showHide();" this from button.

Comment: @Raghubar no need to remove showhide it will work otherwise also

Comment: Are you adding it in master page?

Comment: You cannot call client side JavaScript code withing server side C# code.

Comment: I have Corrected in jsfield now its working check.

Answer (score 5):

You have to select jQuery version from left menu, jsFiddle does `not` support to interpret asp.net code and generate html as asp.net engine do.

[image]

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/fUBPB/2/)**

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('#BtnSend').click(function () {
        $('#loading').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

If you are trying to do same in asp.net and your BtnSend is server control which does not have [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx) set to `static` then you will need to use ClientID to bind event.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('#<%= BtnSend %>').click(function () {
        $('#<%= loading.ClientID %>').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

> The ClientID value is set to the value of the ID property. If the
>   control is a naming container, the control is used as the top of the
>   hierarchy of naming containers for any controls that it contains, [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx).

Comment: its should be `$('#<%= loading.ClientID %>')`

Comment: You can not run asp.net code on jsfiddle, you will need to test it on machine having asp.net